# first duplicate value for a list in range -n to n in O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I was recently solving a problem. The problem simply asks the following,
given a list of integers in range 1 to n, find the first duplicate value in the list,

now the obvious solution is to use a hash table and do it in O(n) space and O(n) time, but I found out there is a  neat trick which we can use to solve it in O(1) space.

We can just iterate the array, and then for `a[i]`, we mark the index `a[a[i]]` as negative, and then we just check if we have made any integer negative before, if yes, that is the first duplicate value.

My question is, what if we have negative values as well in the array? Is there a general approach to solve this?

Comment: Presuming you're storing the array, it still takes O(n) space.

Comment: @qwr if you sort the original array, it doesn't take any additional space, by default any input with size n should take O(n) space which should not be considered in space complexity.

Comment: Solution here: https://youtu.be/pKO9UjSeLew?t=141. The solution reduces the problem to a 2 pointer problem, and doesn't modify the array

Comment: @smac89 can you explain it in an answer?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi you could just watch the video, or look up the algorithm described in the video. The algorithm is called ["Floyd's tortoise and hare"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_tortoise_and_hare).

Comment: @smac89: that solves the original problem where the range of the numbers is the same as the range of array indices. But it doesn't address the problem OP asks: how do you adapt the solution to the case where the range of possible values includes invalid array indices?

Comment: @rici you can simply translate the OP's problem to the problem of finding a duplicate in the range `[1, 2n+1]`; all you need to do is add `n + 1` to each number in that range. Doing that will transform the problem into finding a duplicate in the range 1 to n (where `n` is `2n + 1`). Now you can use the suggestion above to find that duplicate, and your answer will be to subtract `n + 1`  from the result you get

Comment: @smac89: but the array needs to be the same size as the range. Translating the inputs doesn't expand the array. Of course, you can use a bigger array but then the proposed solution is no longer constant space.

Comment: @rici, Ahh I misunderstood the question. I assumed OP is asking how to solve for `1 to n` without modifying the array. Didn't pay attention to the `-n to n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what if we have negative values as well in the array?

If you mean that values are in the range −+1... or −...−1,... such that the count of possible values is 2, then you can reserve 2 bits instead of one for placing flags in the array: one for when the value is positive, and one for when it is negative, or whichever way you want to split the range of values into two.

In your solution you have used the sign bit, which in 32-bit integers typically is the left most bit, or the 32<sup>nd</sup> bit, so you could decide to reserve the 31<sup>st</sup> bit as the second flag. This means  should not be greater than 2<sup>30</sup>−1.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the array itself is O(n) space complexity. If you care about additional space used, all you are doing is using negative values as a flag of 1 bit of storage, which reduces the range of values you can store by 1 bit. You can come up with any number of schemes to store an extra flag bit somewhere: for example, handling values between around int_min/2 and int_max/2, you could shift all values up to be non-negative then use the sign bit, but it is not worth it in practical applications unless you are severely memory constrained. For truly big-data operations, where you cannot even store the whole array, you can use probabilistic online methods like count-min sketch.

Comment: this is a good discussion but I don't think this is a solution in an algorithmic setup.